# RxSwift: Should groupBy send completed to each of its GroupedObservable's when the source is completed?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

The following code never seems to work as the groups don't appear to terminate and takeLast() does not know what is last:

```
observableSequence
  .groupBy { $0.key }
  .map { groups in
    groups
    .takeLast(1)
    .subscribe(onNext: { element in
      print(element)
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
  }
  .subscribe()
  .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

```
    Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
        .groupBy { ($0 % 2) == 0 }
        .subscribe(onNext: { group in
            group
                .takeLast(1)
                .subscribe(onNext: { e in
                    print(e)
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

The above code outputs:

7

8

Answer (score 0):

I still could not get the original more complex version to work but I found another better solution to that which is to reverse the order of the sequence and use take() instead of takeLast(). This worked so I assume that the sequence was not terminating (although I don't see why not).

Anyway, better to take() than takeLast() if you can.